# How can I fix overexposed high resolution photos using Media Foundation?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-media-foundation

I'm using Media Foundation in my WPF application to implement functionality that is similar to the Windows Camera App: show a live webcam feed and take a **high resolution** image when pressing a button. While the Windows Camera App always takes a correctly exposed snapshot, the snapshot taken by Media Foundation is often overexposed.

The application is only used by devices that have built-in high resolutions for Photos (eg Surface Go 2, Surface 7 Pro, ...). A specific image stream is used to take the snapshot instead of reading one frame of the video stream.

I have already tried changing the **IAMCameraControl** and **IAMVideoProcAmp** properties like **Exposure** or  **Brightness** before taking a snapshot but the photo was always overexposed.

Are there any additional settings or approaches for fixing overexposure when taking a high resolution snapshot (eg. the same way the Windows Camera App works)?

**Overexposed snapshot**

[image: Overexposed snapshot]

**High resolutions for photos**

[image: Photo resolution]

**Code to take the snapshot**

```
IMFCaptureEngineClassFactory captureEngineClassFactory = null;
IMFCaptureEngine captureEngine = null;
IMFCapturePhotoSink capturePhotoSink = null;
IMFMediaType photoMediaType = null;
try
{
    // Create a CaptureEngineClassFactory
    captureEngineClassFactory = mff.GetCaptureEngineClassFactory();

    // Create a CaptureEngine
    captureEngine = mff.GetCaptureEngine(captureEngineClassFactory);

    // Initialize the CaptureEngine
    MFCaptureEngineOnEventCallback captureEngineOnEventCallback = MFCaptureEngineOnEventCallback.GetInstance();
    mff.Initialize(captureEngine, captureEngineOnEventCallback, mediaSource);
    captureEngineOnEventCallback.WaitUntilInitialized();

    // Create a Photo Sink
    capturePhotoSink = mff.CreateCapturePhotoSink(captureEngine);

    // Create a Photo Media Type
    photoMediaType = CreatePhotoMediaType(mediaType);

    // Remove all streams
    mff.RemoveAllStreams(capturePhotoSink);

    // Add Stream
    int sinkStreamIndex = mff.AddStream(capturePhotoSink, streamIndex, photoMediaType);

    // Set output filename
    mff.SetSampleCallback(capturePhotoSink, this);

    // Take photo
    mff.TakePhoto(captureEngine);
    captureEngineOnEventCallback.WaitUntilDone();

    // imageSource should be filled in after executing TakePhoto
    return image;
}
finally
{
    TryRelease(captureEngineClassFactory);
    TryRelease(captureEngine);
    TryRelease(capturePhotoSink);
    TryRelease(photoMediaType);
}
```

Comment: You can get closer to what the Camera app does using WinRT instead of MF: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/ (not tested)

Comment: I have rewritten the program to take snapshots using MediaCapture (WinRT). The issue still persists on the Surface Pro 7 device: the snapshot is overexposed. Any chance the source code of the Windows Camera app is available? The Windows Camera app must use different settings because it always takes correctly exposed snapshots.

Comment: Doc is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-device-controls-for-photo-and-video-capture and official sample code similar is there https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CameraManualControls if you don't see a control for exposure, brightness, or other features, then it means it's not exposed by the HW vendor. You can check it with mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ExposureControl.Supported etc.